# c Exit if string is empty

Tags: c, string

I have the below code which is supposed to exit if the provided user input is empty i.e they press [ENTER] when asked for the input. However it doesnt do anything if [ENTER] is pressed.

```
printf("Enter the website URL:\n");
scanf("%s", str);
if(strlen(str) == 0) {
    printf("Empty URL");
    exit(2);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the user just presses enter, the input will still contain a newline (`'\n'`). Your condition should be

```
if (!strcmp(str, "\n"))
```

Comment: This fails if ctrl-d is used, or if input is being redirected from a file. The correct solution would be to trim whitespace from the input and then check for an empty string.

Comment: In a sense this is a correct answer, but it misses a big issue for beginners in C: using scanf instead of a safe replacement like fgets.  I'll upvote if you edit to include a discussion of why scanf is bad.

Answer (score 2):

I use a `isempty` function:

```
int isempty(const char *str)
{
    for (; *str != '\0'; str++)
    {
        if (!isspace(*str))
        {
           return 0;
        }
    }

    return 1;
}
```

Also, I would recommend using `fgets` over `scanf`, as `scanf` is unsafe and can lead to buffer overflows.

```
fgets(str, /* allocated size of str */, stdin);
```

Answer (score 1):

`%s` with `scanf()` will discard any leading whitespace, of which it considers your Enter keypress. If you want to be able to accept an "empty" string, you'll need to accept your input in another way, perhaps using `fgets()`:

```
printf("Enter the website URL:\n");
fgets(str, SIZE_OF_STR, stdin);
if(!strcmp(str,"\n")) {
    printf("Empty URL");
    exit(2);
}
```

Keep in mind the above code does not consider `EOF`, which would leave `str` unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

shouldn't you check for '\n' - new line? Enter will represented as a new line character '\n'